# First widget works in Dashcode but not when deployed

Tags: widget, dashcode

My widget does not work once deployed even though it shows no errors in Dashcode. Apologies in advance for my inarticulartness with the terminology. I am a newbie.

To create the widget, I deleted the default .js file and pasted the JavaScript plus XHTML into the HTML page and created the accompanying CSS file.

The only code I can see that is generated is the plist.

I tried opening up all the permissions but nothing seems to change.

The OSX utilities console shows errors which are on lines beyond what there are numbers for in the code.

I don't think the JavaScript/XHTML/CSS is the problem as it works when in a web page and the widget does actually work within Dashcode.

Help appreciated,

Ruby

Comment: Did you ever get it working? More importantly, I think your title is misleading. From the post, it seems to suggest your widget never worked within Dashcode, nor after deploy/export. But your title suggests it works in Dashcode but not once deployed to dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Dashcode, don't delete the default JS. file. This is important because it has the loaders necessary to render most of the parts in your widget. You can always add your custom javascript file. It also provides code that will allow it to work properly in Dashcode.

Comment: Well, interestingly for me, it works in Dashcode, but not once deployed or exported as widget file. Where it fails to work is persisting session cookie, which works within Dashcode. That's strange. I did overwrite default files of course.

Comment: Try using the built in db instead of a cookie session. https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase.html I stopped developing for dashboard because it's clear that it's on its way out. It's sad, but with the notification center widgets being introduced, dashboard will more than likely go away. First clue was the broken dashcode. :/