# First widget doesn't work in Dashcode but does work when deployed. Can I fix this?

Tags: osx-lion, dashboard, dashcode

I am brand new to Dashcode.  I've created the textbook 'Dashboard Widget Tutorial', using the Countdown template.  When I tell Dashcode to Run the widget, the widget window appears briefly.  (It disappears after less than a second.)  After the widget disappears, dashcode reports it as running.  If I ask Dashcode to Pause, it acknowledges with the log message 'Pausing at the next opportunity'.  There's no further feedback until I typically tell Dashcode to Stop after several minutes.

If I Deploy to Dashboard, the widget works OK.  That's my current work-around, although I'm not sure how I'll fare when I want to debug widgets.

I am using Dashcode 3.0.5 on Lion (10.7.4).

There's an existing question on Stack Overflow [First widget works in Dashcode but not when deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431061/first-widget-works-in-dashcode-but-not-when-deployed).  That is not what's happening to me, I have the 'opposite' problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I guess version 3.0.5 is not working with Lion.

I solved downloading version 3.0.4 ([DashCode for Xcode - March 2012](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/dashcode_for_xcode__march_2012/dashcode_for_xcode.dmg))